# jquery live() onkeyup and click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the live() function to validate a form that is loaded using ajax, since it wont work without it.

Previously, my form validation was done onkeyup (although I never specified it anywhere). Now it works only when the user clicks the submit button. Is it possible to get my onkeyup validation back as well as retain the verify on submit when using the live() function?

```
$(".createBtn").live('click', function() {
$("#createAcc").validate({
```

I'm using the following plugin to do my verification.

```
bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/
```

Comment: As a side note, I would recommend using the on() function, since live() is considered deprecated. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: You can change the 'click' event to anything you want. You probably want to check submit with the `submit` event. As for a `keyup` event your question is a bit vague but I'm assuming you mean it's checking an individual field. In that case you need a separate event. `keyup` may work but personally I'd use `blur`

Comment: jQuery validation plugin has built in params for validation on events like `onKeyUp`, `onSubmit` etc. By default they are all true unless you explicitly override them. Fyi, live is deprecated in all jQuery versions since 1.7 so upgrade the validation plugin and jQuery accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind multiple events to the same element.. try this

```
$(".createBtn").live('click keyup', function() {

    yourFunctionCall();
});
```

Also **.live()** is deprecated as of the latest jQuery version..

I recommend using **.on()** instead..

Comment: This actually works fantastic. But since u said .live() is deprecated, I'm trying to get it to work with .on().

Comment: It depends on the jQuery version you are using.. What is teh version of your jQuery

Comment: .live() is available from 1.3  to 1.7 ( Deprecated in version 1.7).    .on() is available from 1.7 onwards

Comment: I'm using v1.3.2. Since I need jquery for only a few form validation and show, hide etc. I'm having a tuff time with .on() :-)

Comment: .on() is not available on v1.3.2 .. try using .live() instead .. Also to get the latest version you can use the file hosted by google cdn without downloading it .. Just include this and you shall have the latest version <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 2):

You can chain, as Steven said, or you can specify multiple events like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/gLWRs/1/

```
$('.createBtn').on({
  click: myFn,
  keyup: myFn    
});​
```

This also works with `live`.

Re-reading your question though, you'll probably need something like this, because the events will occur on different elements:

```
$('.createBtn').on({ click: myFn });
$('input').on({ keyup: myFn });
```

Comment: nice tweak; but the validation plugin already supports built in features for `onKeyup` and `onSubmit` :)

Answer (score 1):

You could take your function and set it to a variable as follows:

```
var myFn = function() { ... };
```

Then you could register that function with both event handlers.

```
$(".createBtn").on('click', myFn).on('keyup', myFn);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add init of validation into html source that is got from server on document.ready
Some like:

```
if(isAjax)
{
    $(function() {
       // Init you validation
    });
}
```